# With Hibernate NamedNativeQuery, how do I bind these paramters: WHERE (p1, p2) IN ((v1_1, v1_2), (v2_1, v2_2))

Tags: java, hibernate

I want to write a NativeNamedQuery that would allow me to perform the following:

```sql
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE (c1, c2) IN (("v1_1", "v1_2"), ("v2_1", "v2_2"), ...);
```

This is where I got stuck:

```java
@NamedNativeQueries({
     @NamedNativeQuery(
             name = "MyQuery",
             query = "SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE (c1, c2) IN ((:v1, :v2));",
             resultSetMapping = "MyMapper")
})
```

How do I go about binding the combinations of values? ie:

```java
public List<MyDto> something() {

    // This is obviously wrong. Can it be done?
    return (List<MyDto>) getNamedQuery("MyQuery")
            .setParameter(new String[] {"v1", "v2"}, new Object[] {new String[] {"v1_1", "v1_2"}, new String[] {"v2_1", "v2_2"}, ...})
            .list();
}
```

**IMPORTANT:** The number of value combinations must be variable. Meaning I need to be able to use the same named query with parameter sets `new Object[] {new String[] {"v1_1", v1_2}}` or `new Object[] {new String[] {"v1_1", "v1_2"}, new String[] {"v2_1", "v2_2"}}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE** The solution to my own question below. It's not pretty but it is performant and it works.

```java
@NamedNativeQueries({
     @NamedNativeQuery(
             name = "MyQuery",
             query = "SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE c1 IN (:v1) " + 
                         "AND c2 IN (:v2) " +
                         "AND concat(c1, "~", c2) IN (:concatV1V2)",
             resultSetMapping = "MyMapper")
}) 

return (List<MyDto>) getNamedQuery("MyQuery")
        .setParameter("v1", new String[] {"v1_1", "v2_1"})
        .setParameter("v2", new String[] {"v1_2", "v2_2"})
        .setParameter("concatV1V2", new String[] {"v1_1~v1_2", "v2_1~v2_2"})
        .list();
```

The reason I still use the v1 and v2 columns is for performance as these could be indexed. We first narrow down to a small subset of rows and then narrow that down to the desired rows using the (non indexed) concat on the results.